# Express Error 500 :Failed to lookup view "index.html" in views directory "/app/views"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, heroku

```
// App Configuration
app.configure('development', function() {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.tmp')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
});
```

This is my config for rendering files

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index.html" in views directory "/app/views"
>   2015-10-27T23:56:04.240297+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.app.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:493:17)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240299+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.res.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240300+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/lib/config/routes.js:82:9
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240300+00:00 app[web.1]:     at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240301+00:00 app[web.1]:     at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240302+00:00 app[web.1]:     at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240302+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Router._dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240303+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240304+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240306+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:318:9)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240307+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:67:10)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240307+00:00 app[web.1]:     at attempt (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:341:16)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240308+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.authenticate [as handle] (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:342:7)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240309+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240310+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.initialize [as handle] (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:62:5)
>
> 2015-10-27T23:56:04.240311+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `app.get('/index.html',function(req,res){res.render('index.html');});` ??

See this for route examples https://github.com/AugustoL/website/blob/master/routes.js its form my website.

And here you have my server.js, maybe it helps you too https://github.com/AugustoL/website/blob/master/server.js

Comment: Thank you. That help solve my query. i was missing the forward slash in my app.get.

Comment: you are welcome! if you have any other problem write me.

Comment: can you guide or help how to setup/install compass on heroku. I am trying to load a sass file heroku is failing as compass is not installed.